# Tem como utilizar uma variável acima quando ela é declarada abaixo?

Tags: php

Tenho alguns includes em uma página PHP, com inclusão de outras páginas para utilização em URL amigável, etc.
Pensei em utilizar variáveis Globais e até mesmo constantes, porém não está dando certo.

Alguém sabe se existe uma maneira sem ser utilizando Cookies, Sessões ou Cache para utilizar uma variável que só é declarada abaixo?

Exemplo:

```
echo $variavelA;
$variavelA = 1;
```

Nesta lógica, porém obviamente desta maneira não funciona.

---

EXEMPLO MAIS CLARO:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<title><?php echo $pagina; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('home.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Um exemplo muito comum! Vamos supor que no arquivo home.php temos:

```
$pagina = "Home";
```

A variável é declarada abaixo de onde quero chamá-la.

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer necessariamente? Teria como detalhar um pouco mais? Abs

Comment: A sua pergunta é pouco clara por ser tão geral. Tem algum exemplo concreto que quer pôr a funcionar?

Comment: Confira as edições que fiz acima na pergunta...

Comment: Reescrever o código e usar output_flush soluciona? Não programo em PHP, só imagino isso.

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado anteriormente e não funciona pelo que testei...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível chamar uma variável antes da declaração da mesma. Isto é aplicável a qualquer linguagem de programação (como é entendido pelo próprio autor; algumas informações sobre declaração de variáveis no PHP na documentação [aqui](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php)). O que se faz é a declaração de uma variável (constante, função...), em seguida, sua utilização.
Sabendo disso, existem diversas formas de se resolver o problema.

#### Manipulação da tag `<title></title>` com javascript (!)

Talvez uma primeira que venha a mente seja utilizar-se do javascript para a manipulação da tag `<title></title>`. **Porém**, o que deve ser observado neste caso é que o JavaScript é uma linguagem `client-side`, em outras palavras, ele é interpretado ao lado do "cliente". Assim sendo, o sistema sofrerá danos diversos caso seja requisitado em outros ambientes, em motores de busca (Google, Bing...) é um exemplo disso. Logo, torna-se inviável.

```html
<!-- template.php -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('home.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>

<!-- home.php -->
<script>document.title = 'Home';</script>
```

#### Sistemas de templates em PHP

Uma outra seria a utilização de templates. Diversos estão disponíveis no mercado. Poderia citar o `blade` do [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade) (exemplo da versão 5.6), que também pode ser aplicado a outros projetos. Exemplos: [jenssegers/blade](https://github.com/jenssegers/blade), [spatie/laravel-blade](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-blade), e diversos outros.

#### Utilização de seu próprio `template engine`

Para uma manipulação simples e rápida, recomendo a utilização de urls amigáveis com uso de `.htaccess`, e assim fazendo o tratamento da url e, por fim, a inclusão do template que inclui o arquivo `php`.

**Explicação:**

```
# exemplo de estrutura simples de arquivos
├- .htaccess
├- templates/
   └- template.php
├- views/
   └- home/
      └- home.php
├- controllers/
    └- HomeController.php
└- App
   └- Core.php
```

**O .htaccess:**
Este arquivo será responsável pela manipulação da url. Nele você tratará a url e por fim terá o nome da classe e do método que deverá chamar. Separei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277090/4475) uma boa questão (aqui no stackoverflow) a respeito.

**A classe App\Core.php:**
Esta classe receberá as informações contidas na url e por fim deverá chegar até o arquivo `controllers/HomeController.php` (ou outro, conforme a url), e por fim, este, será responsável por setar as variáveis, tanto para `templates/template.php`, quanto para `views/home/home.php` (ou outros arquivos, novamente, conforme a url).

Poderia haver um método parecido com:

```
public function index() {
    $title = 'Bem vindo!';
    return $this->view(array('view'=>'views/home/home.php', 'title'=>$title));
}
```

Por fim, o método `view` buscará o arquivo `templates/template.php` e dentro deste haverá um include para `views/home/home.php` (como chamado pelo `HomeController::index`). O arquivo de template poderia ser parecido com:

```
...
    <title><?php echo "{$data['title']} - Meu site"; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once($data['view']) ;?>
...
```

**Claro! Fazendo as devidas adaptações.**

Comment: Olha, foi a resposta mais prática que solucionou meu problema, não havia pensado na ideia de colocar um script na página. Solucionou de maneira simples e prática, já que não precisei adaptar o site para isto. Obrigado.

Comment: Isso resolve, porém, o problema maior que terá é em relação a SEO.

Comment: Com certeza, essa é uma solução eficaz e resolve o problema, mas existem formas muito melhores e organizadas de resolver esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Você possui alguns exemplos?

Answer (score 2):

Capturando o valor passado via get é possível.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <title> <?php 

                      $pagina= isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : "Inicial";
                      echo $pagina; 

                    ?> 
             </title>
           </head>
           <body>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="?pagina=home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pagina=tutoriais">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pagina=contato">Contato</a></li>                      
</ul>
<?php

    $pg = !isset ($_GET['pagina']) ? $pg == "home" : $_GET['pagina'];

        if( is_file( "$pg.php" ) )
            include "$pg.php";
        else{
            include 'home.php';
        }           

?>
</body>  
</html>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="?pagina=home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pagina=tutoriais">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="?pagina=contato">Contato</a></li>                      
</ul>
<?php

    $pg = !isset ($_GET['pagina']) ? $pg == "home" : $_GET['pagina'];

        if( is_file( "$pg.php" ) )
            include "$pg.php";
        else{
            include 'home.php';
        }           

?>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

isso é meio improvável que você consiga pelo fato que diferente do javascript o PHP é executado apenas quando a página carrega, o que eu recomendo você fazer é uma chamada AJAX para alterar o nome

Comment: Imaginei isto também, achei até que utilizando variáveis globais poderia efetuar tal ação. Mas lhe agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   include('home.php'); 
   $pagina = "Home";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<title><?php echo $pagina; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Em um vídeo de um curso desse modo, pelo menos naquele código deu certo.

Comment: Agradeço seu interesse, dessa maneira eu não poderia porque a página home no caso, possui tags html, já que meu site está fatorado e a index apenas faz os includes das sequencias. Mas agradeço seu interesse em tentar solucionar meu problema!

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não é possível incluir um arquivo .php depois do código que depende do mesmo como já apontado nas respostas; ao meu ver, é até mais simples incluir os arquivos dos quais o código é dependente no topo, pois isso facilita o controle sob as dependências do arquivo.

Portanto, conforme seu exemplo, o código abaixo já se adequaria bem a situação sem mais detalhes:

```
<?php include('home.php')
 /*Se a variável $página do arquivo home.php já contiver o valor 'Home',
  nem é preciso colocá-la aqui.*/
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title> <?php echo($pagina); ?> </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neste caso não seria possível porque tenho o site fatorado por partes. A tem apenas parâmetros lógicos, como conexão com servidor, defines e algumas chamadas de outros includes para montar o site. Assim incluindo a home acima eu estaria mudando a sequência de minhas tags. Porém a resposta abaixo ajudou bastante, agradeço seu interesse em tentar solucionar meu problema!

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei quanto ao SEO mas o `<title>` pode ser colocado fora do `<head>` que o browser lê ele certinho. Pensando no lado do `<title>` vazio adicionando via javascript, é capaz de ter o mesmo efeito (para o SEO, ou ainda melhor no caso do `<title>` fora do lugar preenchido, do que vazio).

Comment: Quanto ao SEO também não sei, mas já utilizei o <title> fora da <head> outras vezes, porém isto é um projeto acadêmico, ficaria então incorreto tal colocação. Agradeço.

Comment: @TiagoBoeing Ah sim! Beleza então.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é impossível, porque declarando:

```
echo $isso;
```

Tu estás a passar um parâmetro que não existe, mas se fores declarar:

```
echo $isso = "Aquilo";
```

Aí a situação muda, porque tu passar um parâmetro a variável $isso, tornando-a legível e avaliável a saída.

Mas declarar `$isso` sem um valor atribuído a variável $isso não irá retornar nada para além de um erro a dizer que a variável não foi definida.

Answer (score 0):

Criei um projeto mobile first inclusive para resoluções 240x340.(celular muito antigo).
Em telas maiores abre as ferramentas na lateral, tipo app.

Imagine um index só de include.
exemplo do meu index

```js
 <?php
     require_once('header.php'); 
     require_once('navmenu.php');
     require_once('logo-perfil.php'); // define tamanhos e medidas aceitáveis
     require_once('conecta_bd.php');// deixa o banco de dado conectado para o próximo include.
 require_once('status.php');// div para ferramentas e o bloco de resultado
 require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

```
  status.php tem três divs principais.
```

Uma de resultado, outras duas de ferramentas para chamar um resultado.

Veja que a div resultado fica no meio do html. Assim gera bug tais como mostrar variável da pagina aclamadas no head.

```
 Solução: Criar ferramentas em forma de formulários
```

```html
<form action="index.php"> <input name="page" value="paginainclude" />
```

Desta forma resolve mais gera no head outro erro. principalmente ao acessar a pagina sem logar, pois o post não foi enviado ainda. coloquei no head a seguinte solução

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="pt-br">

        <head>
          ...
          <?php 
    if(!isset($_POST['page'])){$page_section = "Home";}else{$page_section = $_POST['page'];}
    echo '<title>Santidade - ' . $page_section. '</title>';
    ?> ...

        </head>

        <body>

          ...
          <div id="ferramenta">barra de ferramenta. Ação, chamar arquivo cadastro-> e por na div de resultado " echo'
            <form action="index.php" method="post"><input type="submit" name="page" value="Cadastro"> </form>';. pode ser posto no link em nav Também etc... status.php -> na div id="resultado" eu chamo: require-once('cadastro.php');// registrar novo login... ... serviços do include cadastro
```

" Funcionou
Com o if utilizado no head matou o bug do home e primeiro acesso. Quando a pessoa faz log off ou entra a primeira vez não dá bug, porque a variável $page_section retorna 'home'.

O login como sabem fica no cook ou $section do próprio index que vai servir para cada include. Ou não, se este anular os sections

Desta forma ao gerar o post ele incorpora outro include automaticamente ao ser clicado.

Neste include dentro da div=resultados
É possível fazer uma pagina com novas ferramentas chamando novos includes por exemplo.

Assim é possível criar projetos separados, independentes, com a mesma mascara do "APP".

Foca apenas no contêiner de resultado cujo include é chamado no head controlando toda a pagina.

A seção de login fica em cada cabeçalho include que funciona separado, aproveitando o cookie e acessando os subniveis e login de níveis de acesso.

```
   principal.
```

Evito muita escrita
Ajuda evitar pensar no projeto inteiro a todo tempo.
Facilita colocar paginas independentes, com mysqli solicitados, ou incluir dados. saber a pagina com erros ou contêiner que alguém criou.
Dando erros basta selecionar outra ferramenta. E o cliente não sai da pagina do index.