# Duvida sobre htaccess

Tags: php, html, htaccess, apache, http

Tenho um link amigável que seria `localhost/artists/nome-do-artista/`, porém quero criar páginas dentro dela por exemplo Biografia. `localhost/artists/nome-do-artista/biography`, só que o meu htaccess não permite, como resolver?

Estou utilizando:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [NC,QSA]
```

Em `artists/index.php` está fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados com nome do artista ficando desse jeito o link: `artists/nome-do-artista`.

Porém quando crio `artists/nome-do-artista/biography` ele busca a index principal que seria: `artists/nome-do-artista`.

Espero que tenham entendido, se puderem me ajudar fico lisonjeado.

Answer (score 4):

Como eu não sei como é a sua estrutura de pastas e como você está identificando o nome do artista e etc. Vou deixar uma resposta simples, mas que você pode adaptar.

**Estrutura da Pasta:**

```
.
├── artists
│   ├── albums.php
│   ├── biography.php
│   └── index.php
└── index.php
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule artists/(.*)(?:/(.*))? /artists/index.php?artist=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

Na primeira regra do *rewrite* nós definimos — através do *regex* —, que todo acesso em `http://www.example.com/artists/...` deve ser redirecionado para a pasta `artists/index.php` com os parâmetros definidos.

**Explicando o Regex:**

```
artists/(.*)(?:/(.*))?
└───┬──┘└─┬─┘└──┬────┘
    │     │     └──────── Captura o nome da página. O `?` indica que ele é opcional.
    │     └────────────── Captura o nome do artista
    └──────────────────── Base
```

**artists/index.php**

```
<?php

$artist = $_GET["artist"] ?? false;
$page   = $_GET["page"]   ?? "albums";

if ( $artist ) {

    $model = new ArtistModel();

    if( $model->has($artist) ) {        
        switch ($page) {
            case "biography":
                $content = $model->getBiography();
                require_once "biography.php";
                break;
            case "albums":
            default:
                $content = $model->getAlbums();
                require_once "biography.php";
                break;
        }

    }
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

> **Atenção!** Esse é apenas um exemplo básico. Você não deve usar em produção, apenas para estudos e para ser otimizado/adaptado ao seu código.

Comment: Valdeir, onde posso contatar você?

Comment: Sua explicação visual sobre o regex é o que faltava no site +1

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra resposta (não tão boa quanto a anterior), seria esse htaccess (comentarios no codigo):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# redirecionada todas as urls que terminarem com /biography para a 
# pagina biografia.php (foge um pouco do padrão front controller),
# mas imagino que seja o que você queria inicialmente. 
# O ([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+) captura qualquer caracter alphanumerico incluindo 
# o -, e armazena em $1, que posteriormente é passado para a query
# como nomeartista, que pode ser acessado pelo global 
# $_GET ($_GET['nomeartista']).
# Além disso é passado o argumento [L] indicando que se houver um match 
# esse é o ultimo rewrite.
RewriteRule ^artists/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/biography biografia.php?nomeartista=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Não sei se está dentro das suas possibilidades utilizar algum framework para automatizar a criação de rotas, caso esteja, considere dar uma olhada no [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute).

Para se aprofundar na escrita de htaccess dê uma olhada no guia do [apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html).

Comment: Eu e meu amigo Victor conseguimos de outra maneira, onde o diretorio se encontra **localhost/artists/id/biography**