# Url amigavel .htaccess?

Tags: php, htaccess, url-rewrite

Como eu transformo essa url: 
http://pagina.com.br/detalhe-candidato.php?idcandidato=5&nomecandidato=PC%20Siqueira

nisto:

http://pagina.com.br/5-PC-Siqueira

Com htaccess? Se sim, como?

Obrigado

Comment: Mano, não é duplicata..

Comment: [URL amigável, como fazer funcionar com HTACCESS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973)

Comment: Breve tutorial: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277090/99718