# Pegar valor $_GET com url amigável

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Tenho a seguinte situação, quando a `URL` está sem valores depois da barra `http://www.meusite.com/` e eu digito algo na busca `http://www.meusite.com/?s=teste` inclui minha página de resultado, agora quando a `URL` tem valores `http://www.meusite.com/minha-pagina/?s=teste` não inclui minha página de resultados, como eu poderia arrumar isso?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

```php
$dir = "views/arch";
if (isset($_GET['url'])) :
    $url = addslashes($_GET['url']);
    $sep = explode('/', $url);
endif;

$pg = array('contato');
if (isset($_GET['s'])) :
    require_once (''.$dir.'/search.php');
elseif (isset($sep[0]) && $sep[0] == 'filter') :
    require_once (''.$dir.'/filtro.php');
elseif (isset($sep[1])) :
    require_once (''.$dir.'/categoria.php');
elseif (isset($sep[0]) && in_array($sep[0], $pg)) :
    require_once (''.$dir.'/'.$sep[0].'.php');
else :
    require_once (''.$dir.'/home.php');
endif;
```

Comment: Relacionado: [URL amigável, como fazer funcionar com HTACCESS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53973/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Passando variáveis pela URL utilizando URL amigáveis via GET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27534/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Duvida sobre htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277086/3774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tentou manipular os diretórios no .htaccess? Eu já precisei da seguinte situação:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ arquivo.php?busca=$1 [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/$ arquivo.php?busca=$1 [NC,L]

 RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/([^/.]+)/$ arquivo.php?url=$1&busca=$2[NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Dessa forma, eu determinei exatamente a $_GET['busca'] quando está na raiz ou quando está em outro nível.

**Atualizando**

Quando você envia a variável na raiz do diretório, não precisa do .htaccess para recuperá-lo.

Ao tentar recuperar pelo .htaccess, você utiliza um parâmetro da própria URL para recuperar. Exemplo abaixo:

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1&s=$2 [NC,L] 


</IfModule>
```

index.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


echo 'Minha query de busca:'.$_GET['s'].'<br />';
echo 'Meu diretório:'.$_GET['url'].'<br />';


function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

//QUEBRANDO E EXIBINDO OS FRAGMENTOS DA URL APÓS ?
var_dump(explode("?", curPageURL()));

?>
```

Como pode ver no arquivo, adicionei também uma função caso queira, por algum motivo, coletar a query da URL da forma tradicional também (não amigável como seu exemplo).

Você pode ver o resultado compilado aqui: https://www.crm.ecowd.inf.br/teste/a/c/?search=abc

Espero que tenha ficado mais claro, abraços e boa sorte

Comment: No segundo nível, não precisa ter o Rewrite Rule com e sem barra? Adicionei a linha: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?s=$1 [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/$ index.php?s=$1 [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/([^/.]+)$ index.php?url=$1&s=$2 [NC,L] 

RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/([^/.]+)/$ index.php?url=$1&s=$2 [NC,L]

</IfModule>

Comment: Não vai velho `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 
 RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?s=$1 [NC,L] 
 RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/$ index.php?s=$1 [NC,L] 
 RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/([^/.]+)$ index.php?url=$1&s=$2 [NC,L] 
 RewriteRule ^/?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/([^/.]+)/$ index.php?url=$1&s=$2 [NC,L] 
</IfModule>`

Comment: @goio, complementei a resposta com um exemplo e acho que o maior problema era a transformação de query em parâmetro pelo .htaccess; espero que ajude irmão, abs